# How to pass environment variables to a sbt test build step in Jenkins?

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt

In my scala test, I read an environemnt variable via `sys.props.getOrElse("cassandra.test.host", DEFAULT_CASSANDRA_TEST_HOST)`.

The tests are run via Jenkins.

I have added a `Build using sbt` as a build step.

By looking at similar questions on SO, I came up with this solution - i.e. setting the Actions field to:

`'; set javaOptions += "-Dcassandra.test.host=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX"; test'`

But it doesnt work. No variable is set when `Properties.envOrElse` is executed.

The Jenkins console output contains:

`` [...]
[util-sessionizer] $ java -jar /usr/local/bin/sbt-launch.jar '; set javaOptions += "-Dcassandra.test.host=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX"; test'
[info] Loading project definition from /jenkins/workspace/util-sessionizer/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /jenkins/workspace/util-sessionizer/project
[info] Set current project to util-sessionizer (in build file:/jenkins/workspace/util-sessionizer/)
[info] Defining *:javaOptions
[info] The new value will be used by *:runner, compile:run::runner and 4 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[...] ``

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: I am using scalatest

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're not forking a new JVM to execute your tests, setting `javaOptions` does nothing.
Excerpt from SBT itself:

```
> help javaOptions
Options passed to a new JVM when forking.
```

This explains why your `javaOptions` are not used when you're not forking your tests.

You have basically two solutions:

- Either set `fork in Test := true` to run your tests in forked JVMs
- Or pass your system properties to SBT itself :

  `sbt -Dcassandra.test.host=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX test`

Answer (score 6):

You're setting a system property with `-Dcassandra.test.host=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX"`, but then using `Properties.envOrElse` which is for environment variables. See [Environment Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html).

Try this:

```
  sys.props.getOrElse("cassandra.test.host", DEFAULT_CASSANDRA_TEST_HOST)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding `fork in Test := true` solves the problem - even if, to be honest, I did not investigated the extact corrlation between the two events (i.e. adding `fork in Test := true` and having the system property passed to my tests.

So the correct argument to be passed to sbt is:

`'; set fork in Test := true; set javaOptions += "-Dcassandra.test.host=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX"; test'`