# Passing parameter to scala test, which are executed via sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I'm searching for a simple solution for passing parameters to tests  (using env vars, additional files not suitable. I need to pass values via command line)
Currently I have following solution:
Passing parameters via SBT_OPTS:

```
SBT_OPTS="-DparamName=value" sbt moduleName/test
```

And retrieving value in test:

```
Option(System.getProperty("myProperty")).getOrElse("defaultValue")
```

Unfortunately this solution doesn't fit any more. Are there any simple solutions like this, but without using SBT_OPTS?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627630/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-a-sbt-test-build-step-in-jenkins

Comment: sbt -Dparam=val  module/test

Answer (score 4):

Command:

```
sbt -Dparam=value  module/test
```

Retrieving value:

```
 sys.props.getOrElse("param", DEFAULT_VALUE)
```